# Geting exception "SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app" while running a UI test case using Xamarin UI Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

**I have an iOS app which is not developed using Xamarin**. Now I am trying develop UI test cases for this App Using Xamarin UI test project. I am using Xamarin studio to develop my UI Test Cases in C#.

I am running the test cases in Mac machine.

I am using .ipa file to install the App on to the iOS device. I installed the app and trying to execute below code. Below code is opening the App successfully but failing with below exception 
**"SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to contact test backend running in app. A common cause is that the app is not properly linked with Calabash. Please verify that it includes the Calabash component."**

Code i have used is:

```
IApp app = ConfigureApp.iOS .EnableLocalScreenshots() .DeviceIdentifier("f8c67472f88efb1985c2f5e73698d6bb367807fd").InstalledApp("<<App Bundle ID>>").StartApp();
```

Comment: Did you include the calabash-ios framework in your app?

Comment: I did not to do that. How can i do that?

Comment: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#step-1-link-calabashframework

Answer (score 1):

You must add the Xamarin TestCloud Agent to your iOS solution ; here is the link for the Xamarin package, where you can have a lot of information. Since you're using native iOS I suggest you find the same framework package for native iOS, which should be somewhere on github.

The rest of the setup is still valid wether its Xamarin or iOS

Comment: Hi Zil! You're answer is missing the link.